# Node-Express (module.exports) variable is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

i'll go straight to the subject.

I have 3 files, app.js (that is the main one), cat.js (that has an array of objects) and cats.ejs (the rendered file for a route). Now i want to loop through my arr of obj from my cats.ejs file. I used module.exports = Cats in cat.js and required it in my app.js (but i can use it only in my app.js else will throw variable is not defined).

The question is , what should i do to access the array from my cats.ejs file?
I know I'm not good at explaining things so i'll include 3 images (for each file).

cat.js file [ at the bottom i have module.exports = Cats; ] -> http://prntscr.com/mvwuqs

app.js file -> http://prntscr.com/mvwv7k

cats.ejs file -> http://prntscr.com/mvwvvc

I'm really sorry if this is a stupid question but i couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Instead of screenshot, can you please share the code itself ? It would be easier for us to look into code. (as you have only 3 files, it should be easy for you to insert 3 code block)

Comment: btw, `.render` accepts second arg, where you should be able to pass the `Cats` . something like {Cats, Cats}

Comment: Yep, i thought it's easier for you to share photos, i'm sorry and i'll keep in mind for the next time. I did Colt's bootcamp and i knew about second arg i don't know why i couln't figure it out, thanks so much guys.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include if it wasn't yet resolved, if you did resolve it you could write an answer to this question, or you could delete it if you think this does not have to be answered anymore

Comment: relevant : [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/479251)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Are you exporting cats at the end of the file? If you are doing module.exports, it needs to be an object.

```
module.exports = {
  getCats: function() {
    const Cats = [{}, {}, {}];
    return Cats;
  }
};
```

2. Once you export it, you will be able to access it in app.js. You can pass it to ejs in res.render.

```
let cats = require('./cat');
app.get('/cats', function(req, res) {
  res.render('cats', { CatsData: cats.getCats() });
});
```

3. In your ejs, you can access it this way:

```
<% CatsData.forEach(function(cat, index) { 
    // your data and its properties will be here.
}) %>
```

Comment: `export default` is an es6 specification for exporting module. which is not provided out of the box in node env I think. its module.exports isn't it ?

Comment: Yup, editing the answer right away, thanks :)

Comment: i'm so stupid, i did it before like this few times, idk why i couldn't figure it out. Thanks so much, and i'm really sorry for my stupid question.